Some List Items not editable using .move in SwiftUI List
I modified the default Items example from xcode to include two models, a view with a query and a detail view. On this detail view I cannot properly move all items, only the top two, please see the attached video.
Especially strange is that some dragging does work and some does not. It changes with the number of sub-items on a todo. The models are SwiftData and it is have a one-to-many relationship. On the many relationship the problem exists.
How should the code be adjusted to make sure all items are draggable?
https://imgur.com/a/n1y7iXX
Below is all code necessary for the minimal example. I target iOS 17.5 and this shows on both preview, simulator and my iPhone.
Models
@Model
final class ToDo {
    var timestamp: Date
    var items: [Item]
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.items = []
    }
}

@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    var done: Bool
    
    init(timestamp: Date, done: Bool) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.done = done
    }
}

ItemListView (Here is the problem!)
struct ItemListView: View {
    @Bindable var todo: ToDo
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($todo.items) { $item in
                Text(item.timestamp.description)

            }
            .onMove { indexSet, offset in
                todo.items.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: offset)
            }
        }
        
    }
}

ContentView
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query var items: [ToDo]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        ItemListView(todo: item)
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = ToDo(timestamp: Date())
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(items[index])
            }
        }
    }
}

APP
@main
struct ListProjectApp: App {

    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        
        let schema = Schema([
            ToDo.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(ToDoContainer.create())
    }
}

actor ToDoContainer {
    
    @MainActor
    static func create() -> ModelContainer {
        let schema = Schema([
            ToDo.self,
            Item.self
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        let container = try! ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
                
        
        let todo = ToDo(timestamp: Date())
        
        container.mainContext.insert(todo)

        let item1 = Item(timestamp: Date(), done: false)
        let item2 = Item(timestamp: Date(), done: false)
        let item3 = Item(timestamp: Date(), done: false)
        
        todo.items.append(item1)
        todo.items.append(item2)
        todo.items.append(item3)

        
        return container
    }
}


"todo.items.move", this will never work since the new order will not be persisted so every time the view is refreshed it will show the items in a random order and that order will not be the same once you have restarted the app. To make this work you need a new property on Item for the sort order.

As for the issue with dragging it seems to be some issue between SwiftData and SwiftUI, it looks like in some scenarios there is an update to the ToDo in the database which triggers a view refresh and then the dragging works but in some other scenarios there is no such update so the view is not refreshed.

@JoakimDanielson Thanks! It is possible though to do the foreach on index, could that force the sort order? Workout.haschanges returns true after dragging, so that might be something.

No, you shouldn't do ForEach on indices.

If you just want the re-ordering to "work", without persisting the order, you can use a separate @State to track the order.
struct ItemListView: View {
    let toDo: ToDo
    
    @State var items: [Item] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text(item.timestamp.description)

            }
            .onMove { indexSet, offset in
                items.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: offset)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            items = toDo.items
        }
    }
}


If you want to persist the order, you should add a order property to Item, which you can sort by. Also add an inverse relationship so it's easy to get the items that belong to a ToDo in a Query.
@Model
final class ToDo {
    var timestamp: Date
    
    @Relationship(inverse: \Item.toDo)
    var items: [Item]
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.items = []
    }
}

@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    var done: Bool
    var order = 0
    var toDo: ToDo?
    
    init(timestamp: Date, done: Bool) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.done = done
    }
}

In onMove, calculate the new order and update the order properties.
struct ItemListView: View {
    let toDo: ToDo
    
    @Query var items: [Item]
    
    init(toDo: ToDo) {
        self.toDo = toDo
        let id = toDo.persistentModelID
        self._items = Query(filter: #Predicate<Item> {
            $0.toDo?.persistentModelID == id
        }, sort: \.order)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text(item.timestamp.description)

            }
            .onMove { indexSet, offset in
                // I'm setting the order properties of all the Items,
                // but there is probably a faster way to calculate the new order
                // that only sets the properties that needs to be set
                var copy = items
                copy.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: offset)
                for (item, order) in zip(copy, 0..<copy.count) {
                    item.order = order
                }
                // context.save() here if auto save is off
            }
        }
    }
}


Thanks for the answer! Were you able to run this yourself? I’m not able to get this to work. It results in roughly the same behavior.

@ThomasDeLange Of course! Both versions work for me on iOS 17.4.

My results are that I can only move an item one place up or down. When I try to move it two places up it shifts back again... Like this https://imgur.com/a/OROHbSS. Do you experience this as well @Sweeper?

@ThomasDeLange Oops. The logic for assigning the orders is wrong. I updated the answer.

Ah! It was altering its own list on the go which causes weird behavior. Thanks for the help.
